# Spurious App Crash due to DLL injection because of Thread Local Storage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll-injection, thread-local-storage

a while ago, we had a problem within a Citrix (probably XenApp) environment: Our (Win32) app simply wouldn't start and bailed out with an `ACCESS_VIOLATION`. When I finally got hold of some CoreDump / Minidump files (generation of those was somehow disabled), I noticed the following:

One of the injected DLLs from Citrix had created a thread that got started before the application itself had a chance to finish initializing its Runtime (CRT).

Now, both Windows and VC++ have mechanisms to initialize Thread Local Storage (TLS) data. Windows iteself calls a special entry point in the application *every time* a thread is started. This entry point is handled by the VS CRT which calls TLS initializers. These TLS initializerss may then call constructors of (global) variables that are declared *thread local* via `__declspec(thread)` in code, which is documented and seems perfectly reasonable.

However, since the thread (created by the injected DLL) was started before the app had a chance to complete its initialization, this TLS init mechanism called code that crashed with the `ACCESS_VIOLATION` since the CRT was not fully set up yet.

I tried very hard to write my own DLL that starts a thread, to simulate the behaviour. But I could not get the thread started (and therefore TLS init code called) *before* the apps CRT got initialized.

Of course I managed to implement some workaround, but I find it very disturbing that this is necessary at all. If the OS itself supports initializing TLS, how can it be that some code may create and *start* a thread, before the main apps CRT has been set up? 
Doesn't this destroy all the efforts in having a reasonable and documented TLS behaviour?

Can some please bring some light into this?

Comment: Is this a Citrix ICA client plug in that you are talking about.  Citrix Receiver uses mscrt80.dll family.  Unless you are building with vs2005 things will get strange if you link with other crts too.

Comment: In the context where I could observe the problem: Yes, it was Citrix ICA both times. However, we use static linking of the CRT for our app and try to avoid using DLLs as much as possible (which is something, that is not an option to change). And: It does not interfere in general.

If this were the cause: why and how would this explain that a thread is able to start running before the main apps initialization is done? Is there a call to the OS what signals: "I'm done initializing, you may actually run started threads"?

Comment: So can we confirm? your app is running on the server, not the client desktop?  On the server there is a logon registry key that you have to set on login to start your process if you want to directly interact with Citrix, or is your application "non-Citrix" aware? or linking with vdapi.lib?  I have seen these problems on client side too.  It is possible for a process to inject before CRT startup is done. WH_KEYBOARD_LL hooks can be in another process.  CRT (see source) init is multithreaded for .Net and APC calls can hijack the end of a WaitForMultipleObjects.